# write unicode character for escape telnet

Tags: java, sockets, unicode, special-characters, telnet

i'm writing a java code that connects and executes commands in a telnet based equipment.
when i login, appears a message like this:

```
Trying 10.11.115.160...
Connected to 10.11.115.160.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

the problem is that when i want logout, don't know how to write this char '^]' using a simple string, like this:

```
telnetClient.execute("^]");
```

or

```
telnetClient.execute("\uXXXX");
```

in a linux terminal, it works using ctrl + ].
i don't found this char in the unicode table.

someone knows? thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ctrl + ]` is `U+001D INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE`, so it's `\u001d`. It can be easily checked by running `cat | hexdump` and entering `Ctrl + ]`, `Ctrl + D`.

`U+001B ESCAPE` is `Ctrl + [`.

Answer (score 4):

That character is the "group separator", or `\u001d`.

`^]` comes from a somewhat old way of encoding non-printable character for printing. Characters with an ASCII value (yes, this is way far back from the time when ASCII was still relevant) below 32 were encoded by using the `^` character and another ASCII character for the value, taken in sequence starting with `@`. Therefore NUL (0) becomes `^@`, character number 1 becomes `^A`, 2 becomes `^B` etc. GS happens to have the value of 29, and the 29th character after @ in the ASCII table is `]`.

Edit: Removed embarassing miscalculation ¬__¬